I have 2 different packages with different names
I have been trying minecraft modding recently, but while importing needed packages (via changing build.gradle), I got 2 packages with same ,,name".
2 packages and java importing failure
So, I can't import me.shedaniel.math (first package) because either Java or just IDEA detects only me.shedaniel.rei (second package).
I tried copying all of .math folder, but I couldn't do it. There seems to be something stopping IDEA from directly copying files. I tried making new own-made files and copying contents, but there seems to be a lot of classes that would need to be copied.

‘Two packages with the same name’ is a contradiction in terms.

don't import 2 packages, import only one and where you have to create an object to other package's class, use fully qualified name of that package to be explicit i.e.,
import first.package.with.conflicting.name.*;

public class YourClass {
    public void yourMethod(String whatever) {
        second.package.with.conflicting.name.ItsClass = someApiWhichReturnsItsClass();
        ...
    }
}

by doing this, whenever you specific ItsClass, it will by default to first.package... but when you need second.package... you have to be explicit about it.
